# Why does my model stop printing at the same spot?

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, monoprice-maker-select

I have a [Monoprice Maker Select v2](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=13860) printer which has a printing height of 7".

I tried to print this [trophy](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2638524).

The first time I printed, it stopped about 3/4 of the way (about 5.5").

I use Ultimaker Cura to move the model's z-position down, effectively splitting it in half to print the top half. But on the 2nd print, it seems to have stopped at the same point. There was a lot of extra PLA filament curled up at the end.

[image: Printer trophies]

[image: Slicer view]

Did my printer just jam or am I missing a setting that allows it to print the remaining top portion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that you have not used support structures. The printing fails as a result of missing support structures.

If you look closely to the Ace of Clubs card at the top, you will see that the lower point is being printed from out of nothing, this corner needs to be supported. When unsupported, the extruded filament flows freely and where it deposits is unknown. Usually this extruded filament sticks to the nozzle or ends up stuck at the next piece of the printed layer building up. This build-up can cause the head to hit the print and ruin the print.

To enable support in Ultimaker Cura configure your setting accordingly:
[image: Support settings]

These settings are accessible when you select custom settings:
[image: Advanced or custom Ultimake Cura settings]

If the options aren't visible, use:
[image: Search for settings in Ultimaker Cura]
and type in the option.

*Please do note that using supports does not guarantee that the print will not fail! Especially when using long slender support structures, the chance that a support structure fails increases with the amount of support structures and the length of the structure. Sometimes long slender support structures are knocked over.*

---

*Sidenote:

Your printer has more issues, if you look at the brim, it is not a continuous bed adhesion layer, it looks like it does not adhere too well, see also the bottom of your trophy.*

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I will try out the supports. As for the adhesion issue, I bought a Magigoo Adhesive Pen. I hope that helps. Otherwise, I might go back to a raft instead of a brim, though I found the raft extremely difficult to remove

Comment: @kane Good to hear that, but have you managed to get a whole print considering the other question. If so than we can bag and tag this question. If not please expand the question.